# Magento translate checkout firstname/lastname & prefix

Tags: magento, translation, magento-1.7

How can i translate my magentos 1.6 checkout:
firstname / lastname and prefix of my magento shopper template in german?

thank you
kind regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the PHP method for translations:

Example:

```
<?php echo $this->__('firstname'); ?>
```